# Javascript image uploader

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do I implement an image uploader in javascript with a crop utlility. How do u submit the image file via AJAX? Is the solution cross-domain compatible?

Answer (score 4):

To implement an image upload widget with crop functionality you will have to:

1. **Upload the image to the Server** Uploading files from AJAX applications is a topic on its own. It is best to start with one of the many existing AJAX file upload widgets.
2. **Store the image on the server** After the image has been uploaded to the server, the image URL has to be passed to the crop widget.
3. **Specify the crop region** With the image URL at hand you can write a little crop widget, which lets you define the crop region of the image.
4. **Crop the image on the server** After the user has defined the crop region, the crop data has to be send to the server using an AJAX-call. On the server the image has to be cropped using one of the many image manipulation tools (e.g. ImageMagick).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery you you may take a look at the [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last part of your question - you cannot upload a file using an XmlHttpRequest, so "pure AJAX" won't match here.
What you can do is

```
<FORM method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
     action="serverscript.cgi" target="hiddenframe>
 <input type="file"....
</FORM>
<iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

You will then have to catch the "onload" event of the document in the iframe to know when your document is up there.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use Prototype you may be interested in the jsCropperUI plugin. It has lots of features, and the code is pretty neat.

http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/